# dots in variable names in `js` in shiny app

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

I have tried to reproduce a result from [this example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/1DXjpB_uaRA) but I have a problem with my variables name. What should I do in `CSS/HTML/js` if I have `.` (dot) in my variable name ?

First I have tried the following example which is working and will showing the valuables with tagged colors:

```
t = c("A","B","C")
appCSS <- 
c("#t3 ~ .selectize-control.single .selectize-dropdown [data-value=A] {color:blue}",
  "#t3 ~ .selectize-control.single .selectize-dropdown [data-value=B] {color:red}",
  "#t3 ~ .selectize-control.single .selectize-dropdown [data-value=C] {color:yellow}")

appCSS = str_c(appCSS,collapse = "")

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(

    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(appCSS))),
    selectInput("t3", "Color", t)
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
))
```

Now I do the same, but with changing my vector `t` to `TX2` :

```
TX2
[1] "C-2.20-BL.LK.01-A-A" "C-2.20-BL.LK.01-A-B" "C-2.20-BL.LK.01-A-C"

appCSS <- 
  c("#t3 ~ .selectize-control.single .selectize-dropdown [data-value=C-2.20-BL.LK.01-A-A] {color:blue}",
    "#t3 ~ .selectize-control.single .selectize-dropdown [data-value=C-2.20-BL.LK.01-A-B] {color:red}",
    "#t3 ~ .selectize-control.single .selectize-dropdown [data-value=C-2.20-BL.LK.01-A-C] {color:yellow}")
appCSS = str_c(appCSS,collapse = "")

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(appCSS))),
    selectInput("t3", "Color", TX2)
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
))
```

this does not return the colored variables in dropdown menu. the only difference I could see is my variable names. is it any limit ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [shinyWidgets](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets) package. I allows doing just that.

```
install.packages("shinyWidgets")
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
pickerInput(inputId = "Id068", 
  label = "Style individual options with HTML", 
  choices = c("steelblue 150%", 
    "right align + red", "bold", 
    "background color"), choicesOpt = list(style = c("color: steelblue; font-size: 150%;", 
    "color: firebrick; text-align: right;", 
    "font-weight: bold;", "background: forestgreen; color: white;")))
)

server <- function(inout, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You will find the [demo on shinyapps](https://dreamrs-vic.shinyapps.io/shinyWidgets/).